# install graphviz on openbsd issue

Tags: gcc, freebsd, graphviz

I'm facing a problem installing graphviz 2.29 oj FreeBSD system.
`./configure` works fine but after `make` i see this:

`sftable.c:262: error: 'ptrdiff_t' undeclared`

I'm not familiar to FreeBSD so i don't know what to do with this issue.
It seems to me that it's a known bug (http://www.graphviz.org/bugs/b1019.html) but there's no answer.

Please, help!

ps: `gcc version 4.2.1 20070719`

`FreeBSD 7.3-RELEASE-p2`

Comment: Do you absolutely need version 2.29?  You might try instead installing 2.26.3 from the ports collection, which I presume would compile and install fine.

Comment: now i'm using 2.26 from ports, but i know, that neato in 2.29 works better for my task.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One way to install software that is newer then the port's version is to change the port's version (using graphviz as example):

```
% cd /usr/ports/graphics/graphviz
```

Edit the `Makefile` and change `PORTVERSION` to match the version you want. Comment any `PORTREVISION` and leave `PORTEPOCH` alone.

```
% sudo make makesum
% sudo make
```

In a lot of cases this simply works, because the patches that the port maintainer applies to make things work, don't always make it upstream timely. If this don't work and your knowledge is of the ports system is minimal, you might want to stop, if not or eager to learn, then read the errors and try to resolve them.

Answer (score 0):

Well, then try to add this line:

```
#include <stddef.h>
```

at the top of sftable.c file.